# Сan’t ask permission to permanently receive geolocation

Tags: expo

```
  async function rememberLocation () {
        let { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
        console.log(status);
        let { status2 } = await Location.requestBackgroundPermissionsAsync();
        console.log(status2)
    }
```

This is my code for asking permission. As you can see, first there is a request for permission during use, and then for use in the background. requestForegroundPermissionsAsync works without problems, and I see “granted” in the console. And the second one ends with an error and the window asking for permission does not appear. There is a warning in the console:
"Possible unhandled promise rejection (id: 0):
Error: One of the 'NSLocation*UsageDescription keys must be present in Info.plist to be able to use geolocation."

My app.json:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "assistant",
    "slug": "assistant",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "plugins": [
      [
        "expo-location",
        {
          "locationAlwaysAndWhenInUsePermission": "Allow assistant to use your location.",
          "locationAlwaysPermission": "sdfsdfsdfsdfdf",
          "locationWhenInUsePermission": "ddfdfdfdfdfd",
          "isIosBackgroundLocationEnabled": true
        }
      ]
    ],
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "infoPlist": {
        "UIBackgroundModes": ["location", "fetch", "remote-notification"],
        "NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription": "...",
        "NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription": "...",
        "NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription": "..."
      }
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      }
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    }
  }
}
```

I'm starting a project on ubuntu 22.04 with the npx expo start command. Tell me why it doesn't work and what needs to be fixed?